# Hyper-V, NLB, ARR cannot connect 1 host to another

Tags: hyper-v, arr, nlb

I'm having trouble connecting 1 host to another even with windows firewall off on bot the VM and the host machines they cannot seem to find each other.

**Running Windows Server 2019**

HyperV Host1:

- VM Domain Controller (Connected to domain)
- VM NLB1 (Connected to domain)

HyerV Host2:

- VM NLB2 (Connected to domain)

*I've tried turning off firewall on both host machines and NLB Vm's but i cannot connect 1 host to another.*

*UPDATE
I'm trying to create an NLB Cluster with ARR that can forward requests to 2 webservers. I'm running into issues trying to connect the two ARR machines together into a cluster.

Comment: What do you mean you can't connect 1 host to another? What are you trying to do? You need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: so i've installed NLB on both VM's and i created a cluster on one of them. I'm trying to connect the 2nd VM into the cluster but when doing so it's giving me that error "Host not found" @joeqwerty